# using kivy image like buttons

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I tried to make an kivy program with images which do something (a print massage) but it does not work.
I am not even getting an error message, all I get is an black screen.
It seems like the program opens, but the images are not displayed.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty

root_widget = Builder.load_string('''
<Root>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
    Knopf:
        pos: 400, 100
    BILD1:
        pos: root.Width/4, root.Height/4
    BILD2:
        pos: root.Width/2, root.Height/4
    BILD3:
        pos: root.Width/4, root.Height/2
    BILD4:
        pos: root.Width/2, root.Height/2
<Knopf>:
    Image:
        pos: root.pos
        id: my_image
        source: 'bestatigung.png'
<BILD1>:
    Image:
        pos: root.pos
        id: pic1
        source: 'Bild1.png'
<BILD2>:
    Image:
        pos: root.pos
        id: pic2
        source: 'Bild2.png'
<BILD3>:
    Image:
        pos: root.pos
        id: pic3
        source: 'Bild3.png'
<BILD4>:
    Image:
        pos: root.pos
        id: pic4
        source: 'Bild4.png'
''')
class Root(Widget):
    pass

class Knopf(Widget):
    Width = NumericProperty(Window.width)
    Height = NumericProperty(Window.height)
    velocity = ListProperty([1, 0])

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Knopf, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.Update, 1/60.)

    def Update(self, *args):
        pass

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print 'es geht'
            
class BILD1(Knopf):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print 'es geht'
class BILD2(Knopf):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print 'es geht'
class BILD3(Knopf):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print Window.width
class BILD4(Knopf):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print Window.height
class app(App):
    def build(self):
        return root_widget

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your kv string doesn't define a root widget, so `root_widget` is just None.

You could instead do

```
def build(self):
        return Root()
```